# Is list comprehension appropriate here?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, duplicates

I have to append elements to a list only if the current iterated element is not already in the list.

```
>>> l = [1, 2]
>>> for x in (2, 3, 4):
...     if x not in l:
...             l.append(x)
... 
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

vs

```
>>> l = [1, 2]
>>> [l.append(i) for i in (2, 3, 4) if i not in l]
[None, None]
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

The list comprehension gives the result is what I want, just the returned list is useless. Is this a good use case for list comprehensions?

The iteration is a good solution, but I'm wondering if there is a more idiomatic way to do this?

Comment: For some reason I'm not able to edit my question again. I forgot to say that I care for the order of elements.

Comment: In the daily usage I'll have to mediate between the proposed solutions. Gerrat's is compact, TokenMacGuy's is explicit and fast, while tyz's places itself in the middle, compact and fast though less immediate. THANKS for the great answers. I checked Gerrat answer because it's closer to my original intent.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do:

```
l.extend((i for i in (2,3,4) if i not in l))
```

This solution still works if the added list is non-unique.

Comment: this code will get different result when the numbers to be appended are not unique. such as: (2,3,4,4)

Comment: @user772649: If that's a possibility, then simply wrapping a `set` around the group of numbers to be added will solve that.

Comment: use set() if the position information is not important. set() will change the order of the sequence.

Comment: @user772649:  Correct...and oddly enough, I was just about to point that out in a comment to the other answer (that was removed).

Comment: @user772649 this code handles appending non-unique numbers.  The generator expression is evaluated one number at a time in `list.extend` so the condition is evaluated on the latest contents of `l`.  Try `l = [1, 2]; l.extend(i for i in (2, 3, 3) if i not in l)`.  You will get different results if you use a list comprehension instead of a generator expression.

Comment: @Peter:  Wow...nice catch.  I just thought this would fail as well without thinking about the way that the generator expression works.

Comment: @Perter: yes, you are right, I didn't realize that it's a  generator expression.

Answer (score 7):

This algorithm, either with or without a list comprehension, is not as efficient as possible;  `list.__contains__` is O(n), and so adding the elements of another list to it is O(n<sup>2</sup>).  On the other hand, `set.__contains__` is O(log n), so the *best* way to do this is to use a set to check for membership, and a list to preserve order.  That way you're doing n operations that are O(log n), for a total of O(n log n), which much faster than O(n<sup>2</sup>) for reasonable values of n (above say, 100 elements).

```
>>> l = [1, 2]
>>> seen = set(l)
>>> for x in (2, 3, 4):
...     if x not in seen:
...         seen.add(x)
...         l.append(x)
... 
>>> l
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using list comprehensions just for sideeffects is discouraged. There is nothing wrong with the 3 line version.

If `l` gets really long, you may want to maintain a set in parallel to avoid using `in l` on the long list

Answer (score 3):

I can suggest one more solution:

```
orig = [1,2]
ext = [2,3,4]
orig.extend(filter( lambda x,p=set(orig):not(x in p or p.add(x)),ext ))
```

It takes into account element order and works in case of element repetition.

BTW, complexity is O(n*log(n)).

Comment: excessive cleverness, +1 anyway.